# ios UIGestureRecognizer for longpress, then swipe

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I'm using a UIGestureRecognizer to recognize a single tap, a double tap and a longpress.

What I would like to do is also recognize a longpress, then swipe to either left or right.

Would this be possible given that I'm already consuming a longpress?  I'm confused on this one and would appreciate pointers on how to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this out myself and it seems as if the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` will transition to its end state as soon as the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` begins. Just make sure `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` returns YES for this gesture combination.

Comment: Thanks....worked a treat. I also had UIPanGestureRecognizer incorporated which caused interference. So I had to look at otherGestureRecognizer to get the desired behavior

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use two gesture recognisers and make sure you track the state of the long press one when you receive a callback to say it's ended, and then do something based on the swipe/pan gesture following it.